# Install TopShelf service from C# Application

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

Hi I am trying to install a service (created with TopShelf) from a Windows Forms Application, in c#.
I was looking at using the Service Manager Class but this doesn't seem to be an option. I therefore Was thinking of using the  Process class to invoke the install.
usually to install a Topshelf service you run the following :

> MyService.EXE install -someOptions

However when I try this within a Process

> ```
>  var servicePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Blah Services\bin\Gateway\Gateway.exe";
>  var userName = "test";
>  var password = "Word!";
>  
>  try{
>       Process proc = new Process(); //call new Process
>         ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(); //call new ProcessStartInfo
>         info.Arguments = "install -instance:default -username:" + userName + "-password:" + password;
>         info.FileName = servicePath; //set the file name (location)
>
>         proc.StartInfo = info; //put the StartInfo into the Procces method
>         proc.Start(); //Start the procces (sc.exe with the arguments)
>         proc.WaitForExit(); //waits till the procces is don
>      
>    }
> ```

I even thought about using a command window and replacing the Arguments and File name with the following:

```
   info.Arguments = "//k " + servicePath +" install -instance:default -username:" + userName + "-password:" + password;
            info.FileName = "cmd.exe"; //set the file name (location)
```

Neither seem to be working though. Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab at it, but are you running your WinForms app (or Visual Studio) as an administrator? I have been using the following to fire TopShelf installations as an admin:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\winServices\extracts\bin\service.exe", "install");
```

Comment: "administrator" did it for me, Thanks!